# Call by reference function and syntax

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

The code sorts 3 numbers in ascending order. But, `swap` function has already been invoked by reference. Why must also `sort` function be invoked by reference ? My question is that swap function has already been invoked by reference. So, why also need sort function by reference ? I'm confused. Secondly, `cout << endl,` doesn't give any error so, I've pressed wrongly the comma. How come ?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


void swap ( int& a, int& b );
void sort ( int a, int b, int c );


int main() {

    int num1, num2, num3;

    cout << "Enter first number => ";
    cin  >> num1;
    cout << "Enter second number => ";
    cin  >> num2;
    cout << "Enter third number => ";
    cin  >> num3;

    cout << endl,
    cout << "Before sorting numbers\n" << num1
         << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << endl;

    sort( num1, num2, num3 );

    cout << "After sorting numbers\n" << num1
    << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << endl;

    return 0;
}


void swap ( int& a, int& b ) {

    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
void sort ( int a, int b, int c ) {
//void sort ( int& a, int& b, int& c )

    if (a > b)
        swap(a, b);

    if (a > c)
        swap(a, c);

    if (b > c)
        swap(b, c);
}
```

Comment: How would `num2` and `num3` change in `main()` if you dont pass them by reference?

Comment: You do know that there exists a [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and a [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function in the `std` namespace? By having `using namespace std` in your code, your own function can cause clashes with the standard functions, especially the `swap` function in this specific case.

Comment: Also, you have two different and unrelated questions, and for that you should post two different questions.

Comment: That's just the [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c). It'll evaluate `cout << endl`, throw away the result, then evaluate the other `cout` expression.

Answer (score -1):

When you call your `sort` function, three new variables are created in the scope of that function. These variables are copies of the three variables you pass it in your `main` function. Those three variables are going to be passed into the `swap` function, which takes two integer addresses. The variable address that you're passing it is only scoped to within the `sort` function. You could probably use pointers to keep everything more organized.

```
int main() {

    int *num1, *num2, *num3;

    cout << "Enter first number => ";
    cin  >> *num1;
    cout << "Enter second number => ";
    cin  >> *num2;
    cout << "Enter third number => ";
    cin  >> *num3;

    cout << endl,
    cout << "Before sorting numbers\n" << *num1
         << " " << *num2 << " " << *num3 << endl;

    sort( num1, num2, num3 );

    cout << "After sorting numbers\n" << *num1
    << " " << *num2 << " " << *num3 << endl;

    return 0;
}


void swap ( int *a, int *b ) {

    int *temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
void sort ( int *a, int *b, int *c ) {

    if (*a > *b)
        swap(a, b);

    if (*a > *c)
        swap(a, c);

    if (*b > *c)
        swap(b, c);
}
```

I didn't actually have a chance to compile this, but I will later today to see if it works.

Comment: That won't work because you are passing `int` to a function expecting `int*`. Why use pointers instead of just using references for both functions?

Comment: This code has serious problems. Inside `main` the variables `num1`, `num2`, `num3` are _uninitialized pointers_. If you're lucky the program will crash when you try to dereference them. The `swap` function has no effect because you're swapping passed-by-value parameters around instead of the values they point to.